# Single instance of ATL COM class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, atl

I have a COM class. It can be accessed by processes outside my own. Each process creates it's own instance of the class. Is there a way to have a COM object that is shared amongst all processes that CreateInstance() it?

COM Singleton is the only thing that comes to mind. However, I don't have any experience using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codebase I inherited accomplishes this by declaring a static 'implementation' instance in the COM project.

The COM class simply offers an interface to that instance. This way, multiple instances of the COM class effectively provide access to a singleton implementation object within the COM server.

Note that this often requires synchronization constructs.

Comment: Would CreateInstance(..., CLSCTX_SERVER, ...) accomplish the same thing? Basically the instance lives on the server side and clients only connect to it?

Comment: If it's in a DLL, no it will fail. CLSCTX_SERVER implies that a standalone EXE server exists, and can be run as a process. COM+ is your friend here.

Comment: Is DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY_SINGLETON the answer? Will it allow for a single instance to live between my C++ code and client JScript code?

Comment: @Hans, my undestanding is that DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY_SINGLETON violates the IClassFactory::CreateInstance() contract and COM's identity rules and that it should have never been included in ATL. I saw Don Box express it best during TechEd'99 when he, in front of an audience of hundreds and in his trademark theatrical fashion, opened up the ATL source files in Program Files and summarily deleted the macro definition. Unless somehow MS fixed it, but I believe it was a fundamental problem. Or, unless Box was wrong, which didn't happen often when it comes to COM. I don't remember all the details.

Comment: Contrast DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY_SINGLETON with the approach in this answer. With DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY_SINGLETON, your CreateObject() will provide to COM the same COM interface pointer everytime it gets asked. It's lying to COM, which expects a new pointer to a new COM object. In this solution, instead, there is a singleton, but CreateObject is providing **new** COM objects that wrap the singleton non-COM object for the COM client. This approach does respect the COM rules. The COM objects are independent and follow COM's lifetime rules; that they all call a shared object is irrelevant to COM.

Comment: @EuroMicelli What rule is that? It is perfectly ok to return the same object. Objects when queried to `IUnknown` [are only considered identical to prior calls if the IUnknowns are equal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)).   The fact that this COM equality rule exists to this day means implies it is perfectly acceptible..  By the way, Adam's answer and Microsoft's .NET _Runtime Callable Wrapper_ are _"violating"_ according to what you say.  Who knows, maybe RCW is using DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY_SINGLETON under the hood

Comment: @MickyD IUnknown comparison rule is true, but you shouldn't make that inference; there are ways to get objects other than by IClassFactory::CreateInstance for example. I gave all I remembered at the time in my 2011 comments. Don Box gives a 4-page explanation in "Effective COM" #4 (Box, et al 1999 Addison-Wesley). Key aspect is that CreateInstance is documented as "*...  **creates an uninitialized object** of the class identified...*" (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iclassfactory-createinstance). Post as a Question, and I'll try to summarize his argument.

Comment: @EuroMicelli ah, interesting! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

COM singleton in an out-of-process server. If the server is already implemented in a DLL, consider using COM+ to configure it as out-of-process. This way, you'll get the best of both worlds.

Comment: I do have an EXE with my COM object defined in it. There will be some JScript that instantiates the object (or gets a reference of it, if already exists) and uses it. In my EXE, similarge code (C++) will either create or get a reference to an already existing object.